# Is it possible to get a literal from the JsonProvider?

Tags: .net, f#, .net-standard

```
type ConnectionStrings = JsonProvider<"devAppsettings.json">

let rtDb = ConnectionStrings.GetSample().ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection
```

I am trying to grab the connection string from a json file for use by SqlCommandProvider, but I get the error:

> This is not a valid constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible, since literals are assigned during compilation and JsonProvider accesses values on runtime.
You could try to tackle this issue by using connection string name

```
type Test = SqlCommandProvider<"SELECT * From Test", "name=TestDb">
```

but you'd have to ditch the Json config to Xml version.